# Stuck at black screen after boot from fresh install, Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia

**Computer Specs**

Asus Zenbook UX433FN

i7-8565U

512GB PCIe NVMe, 16GB RAM DDR3

Nvidia MX150 **(!)**

**Background**

Just successfully installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my computer (specs above). Secure boot off, fast boot off. Used `nomodeset` parameter for both install and boot.

Dual boot Windows 10 UEFI.

Partitioned around 230GB for Ubuntu.

Used minimum install and option to install 3rd party drivers.

**Problem**

After booting up Ubuntu from said fresh install, *stuck at black screen with blinking cursor.*

Boot options: `nomodeset` *(`quiet splash` or lack thereof doesn't make a difference)*

Most of the solutions advise nomodeset but I already did that... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**, but not sure what helped to solve the issue. Did the following:

1) Added boot options: `nomodeset acpi_iso="!Windows 2018"`

> Still stuck at black screen

2) Used ctrl-alt-F2 to switch to TTY2 (and thus got terminal)

3) Downloaded proprietary Nvidia drivers as per https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/:

`$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`

4) Went back to TTY1 (ctrl-alt-F1) > Sadness.

5) Went back to TTY2 (ctrl-alt-F1) > Magic! Worked!

I have no idea what exactly solved the issue, whether it was `acpi_iso` or the Nvidia drivers, or both, though I suspect the latter made all the difference.